# asp.net web api server data not syncing with database between BL

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

Hello I am new to servers and REST API and am trying to extract data from a dynamically created table and the data does not sync with the data in the database.
I have an sql database from which I extracted an entity database in asp.net web project.

This is an example for GET of one entity class (exists in database):

```
    public class EmployeeBL
{
    private FSProject1Entities db = new FSProject1Entities();

    public List<Employee> GetEmployees(string fname, string lname, string depID)
    {
        return GetEmployeeSearchResult(fname, lname, depID);        
    }
}
```

And this is an example for a method from a class such as I created in order to combine data from 2 tables:

```
public class ShiftEmployeeDataBL
{
    private FSProject1Entities db = new FSProject1Entities();

     private List<ShiftEmployeeDataBL> GetEmployeeByShiftID(int id)
    {
        List<ShiftEmployeeDataBL> shiftEmpData = new List<ShiftEmployeeDataBL>();
        foreach (Employee emp in db.Employee)
        {//build list... }
        return shiftEmpData;
    }
```

My problem is that db.Employee via this GET request path (ShiftEmployeeData) is old data and via Employee GET request is good data (assuming the data was updated via Employee path).

And vice versa - it would appear that if I update Employee via ShiftEmployeeData class, it would appear as good data for ShiftEmployeeData class and not update for Employee.

I have APIcontrollers for both classes.
what is happening? I feel like I am missing something.
I tried closing cache options in browser.

**update with code for elaboration:**

entity Employee:

```
   public partial class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int StartWorkYear { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
}
```

employee update(auto generated by entity model code generation from db):

```
 public void UpdateEmployee(int id, Employee employee)
    {
        Employee  emp= db.Employee.Where(x => x.ID == id).First();

        emp.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
        emp.LastName = employee.LastName;            
        emp.StartWorkYear = employee.StartWorkYear;
        emp.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID;
        
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

employeeshiftdata class (not a db table but still in the models folder):

```
    public class EmployeeShiftData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }  //EmployeeID
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int StartWorkYear { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public List<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
}
```

employeeshift GET part of the controller:

```
   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class EmployeeShiftDataController : ApiController
{
    private static EmployeeShiftDataBL empShiftDataBL = new EmployeeShiftDataBL();
    // GET: api/EmployeeShiftData
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeShiftData> Get(string FirstName = "", string LastName = "", string Department = "")
    {
        return empShiftDataBL.GetAllEmployeeShiftData(FirstName, LastName, Department);
    }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see the code that interacts with the database, especially the code that makes the updates.

If the changes are written with Entity Framework, are the models themselves properly related with navigational properties?

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<EmployeeShift> EmployeeShifts { get; set; }
  // etc.
}

public class EmployeeShift
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Int EmployeeID { get; set; }
  public Employee Employee { get; set; }
  // etc.
}
```

If those are good, and both models are covered by Entity Framework's context tracking, then both should be updated.

Comment: The models that are created via the entity auto generation should be good I believe.
For those I created, I did create a class, a BL and an ApiController.
I will post the classes if it will help.
I am not sure what you meant by context tracking though.

Comment: I don't need EmployeeShiftData to save data as EmployeeShiftData object so I didn;t manually add it to the DbContext if that is what you referred to but should I really? it only returns data from classes already in the DbContext.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example